# div should appear with animation

Tags: jquery

I want to show  a animation to  my div control.
When page is load div should be hidden , when  user click a button div should appear with some animation I want to show a sliding animation on my div control, this should happen if a button is click.
I have to do it in jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn").click(function(){
    $(".divClass").slideToggle("slow");

  });
});
```

other options are `slideDown, slideUp, slideToggle,fadeIn, fadeOut, fadeTo`

A complete example is as follow

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn").click(function(){
    $(".divClass").slideToggle("slow");

  });
});
</script>

<style type="text/css"> 
.divClass
{
margin:0px;
padding:5px;
text-align:center;
background:#e5eecc;
border:solid 1px #c3c3c3;
height:120px;
display:none;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="divClass">
<p>This is a sample JQuery Animation</p>
<p>Your text or control goes here...Your text or control goes here....Your text or control goes here</p>
</div>

<input id="btn" type="button"  value="Show Div" />

</body>
</html>
```